# req.cookies not being send to the back-end for JWT authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, axios

I know this question has been asked a 1000 times on Stack Overflow but none of the solutions seem to fit mine. I've also been through a lot of GitHub repo's but I just can't seem to find the solution. Also this is my first experience with developing a back-end.

### The problem

I created a backend with authentication including refresh token and refresh token rotation. When I try to log in / sign up / request a request token in Insomnia I don't have any issues at all. Within MongoDB my refreshToken gets updated, I retrieve a new access and refreshtoken after calling the /refresh endpoint. However when I try to do call the refresh endpoint from the browser, I get an error "401 unauthorized" on the first step because it does not see the cookie. When trying to log the cookie I get [Object: null prototype] {}.

I know I am in development so what I've already tried:

- Set withCredentials: true for the axios calls
- Added credentials: true and origin: true to the cors config
- Setting secure: false for res.cookie()

When I try this from my React front-end I do bump into some issues.

**- Login endpoint properly sends the accessToken in the json and the refreshToken as a HTTPOnly Cookie**

[image: Response from the backend after logging in]

**- Response from backend when calling the refresh endpoint**

[image: Response from the backend after refresh]

When I try to console.log the req.cookies I get [Object: null prototype] {}.

Here are some parts of my code:

Server.js

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const connectDB = require("../server/configs/db");
const errorHandlerMiddleware = require("../server/middleware/error-handler");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const verifyJWT = require("./middleware/verifyJWT");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

//Connect Database
connectDB();
const db = mongoose.connection;

// Middleware
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);

//Serve public folder
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));

//Routes
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/authRoutes"));
app.use("/api/logout", require("./routes/logoutRoutes"));

//Protected routes
app.use(verifyJWT);
app.use("/api/habitcards", require("./routes/habitcardRoutes"));

db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connected to database");
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
  });
});

// Log errors on occurence

db.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error connecting to database", err);
});
```

The refresh controller

```
  //Get the refresh token from the request
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;

  console.log(cookies);
  console.log("step");

  //Check if the refresh token is present
  if (!refreshToken) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
  }
  //Remove the old refresh token from the client
  res.clearCookie("jwt", { httpOnly: true, secure: false, sameSite: "none" });

  //Check if the user exists
  const user = await User.findOne({ refreshToken }).select("-password").exec();

  //If the user does not exist then the refreshToken does not exist anymore
  // Check to which user the refreshToken (Refresh token container user ID) and delete all refresh tokens for that user
  if (!user) {
    jwt.verify(
      refreshToken,
      process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
      async (err, user) => {
        //Return Forbidden when token is invalid
        console.log("hoi");
        if (err) return res.status(403).json({ message: "Forbidden" });
        //Delete all refresh tokens for that user if token is valid (Maybe warn the user?)
        const hackedUser = await User.findById(decoded.userId);
        hackedUser.refreshToken = [];
        await hackedUser.save();
      }
    );
    return res.sendStatus(403);
  }

  //Make sure the new refreshtoken is not the same as the old one
  const newRefreshTokenArray = user.refreshToken.filter(
    (rt) => rt !== refreshToken
  );

  jwt.verify(
    refreshToken,
    process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
    asyncHandler(async (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        user.refreshToken = [...newRefreshTokenArray];
        const result = await user.save();
      }

      if (err || user.email !== decoded.email)
        return res.status(403).json({ msg: "Forbidden" }); // Forbidden

      //Refresh token was still valid
      const roles = Object.values(user.roles);

      //Create a new accessToken and refreshToken and return to the user
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        { userInfo: { userId: user.id, roles: roles } },
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        {
          expiresIn: "30s",
        }
      );

      const newRefreshToken = jwt.sign(
        { userId: user.id, email: user.email },
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        {
          expiresIn: "1d",
        }
      );

      //Save the new refresh token to the user
      user.refreshToken = [...newRefreshTokenArray, newRefreshToken];
      const result = await user.save();

      res.cookie("jwt", newRefreshToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        sameSite: "none",
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      });

      res.json({ accessToken });
    })
  );
};
```

The Refresh call from the Front-End (Not complete since I was trying to debug and just make a simple call)

```
  const useAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/users",
    withCredentials: true,
    crossDomain: true,
  });

  const refresh = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await useAxios.get("/refresh");
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

What can I try to solve this issue?

**Latest request made to the back-end:**
[image]

The response that gets sent by the signin endpoint
[image: Response of signin]

Comment: Setting a cookie with `SameSite=None` also requires the `Secure` cookie attribute ([at least in Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/)). Otherwise, the browser ignores attempts to set such a cookie. And you cannot set a `Secure` cookie from an insecure origin like `http://localhost:5000` (see step 13 in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/#section-5.6).

Comment: Thanks, for the quick answer. I have said Secure to false everywhere because i've read in a lot of articles that secure="true" does not work when working on a localhost environment. Removed all the SameSite=none which by default should set it to Lax according to documentation but this did not seem to solve the problem for me.

Comment: Setting the cookie with `Lax` won't work either if you access your client at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. The request sent from `http://127.0.0.1:8000` to `http://localhost:5000` won't carry your cookie as the request is considered [_cross-site_](https://web.dev/same-site-same-origin/). `localhost` may resolve to `127.0.0.1` but, as far as the browser is concerned, `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and `http://localhost:5000` are not same-site. Try accessing your client at `http://localhost:8000` instead. Then, the request to `http://localhost:5000` will be considered same-site and will carry the cookie.

Comment: Allright I have tried your last option but I am still getting a 401 and the cookie gets logged as an Object: null. I also created an array with whitelisted origins including localhost and 127.0.0.1. I will add the image at the end of my question, as you can see the question.

Comment: Please confirm that the cookie is actually getting set in your browser.

Comment: I have also added the response of the signin endpoint which includes Set-Cookie jwt. When I remove httpOnly I should be able to see the cookie within application after signing in right? Because when I do that the cookies don't appear. I do know httpOnly cookies are not accessible by JS, is there another way to check if it actually gets set?

Comment: You can see the cookies in Chromium's Application tab or Firefox's Storage tab.

Comment: I knew that it was possible to view cookies in the application and storage tab's but I was in the misunderstanding that httpOnly cookies could not be shown. There was an issue with my signin call which also needed { withCredentials: true }, here I was thinking this was only to send credentials towards the server but it's also for receiving. Merci beaucoup Julien!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jub0bs I was able to solve this problem.

I was not correctly setting the cookies because when signin in my  axios post call did not have the qithCredentials parameter. I was in the misunderstanding that the withCredentials was only used for sending credentials and not for receiving.

**Solution:**
Add the axios parameter { withCredentials: true } to post requests.

```
  const signin = async (formValues) => {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/users/signin",
      { ...formValues },
      { withCredentials: true }
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a solution that will work ... since new update in chromium engine you have to use sameSite=None with secure=true but than it asks for server to be of https , therefore before proceeding or sending cookies to browser
you have to make your server https not http now see how to make a https server and then implement your code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).